# Change a Universal App Into one without native iPad support

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-universal-app

We are currently developing a universal application. However due to budget and timeline constants, the powers that be have decided to delay the deployment of the iPad version of the application.

How can we disable to iPad specific features of a universal application, without having to create a totally new project and migrate source and content files over.
Ideally I would like the application to run the iPhone version of the application when installed on the iPad.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can just change the drop down in the project summary from Universal to iPhone. Your classes will all remain, but will only target iPhone. So long as your Universal iPad code was done correctly, it shouldn't affect your iPhone build. When you are ready to pick back up for Universal builds, just flip it back, and all the code should be there from before. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply Bill. In addition to this, I also had to change the value of the key "Main storyboard file base name (iPad)" within the application plist file.

Comment: Ah, ok. Good to know. I'm working on a universal version too, but adding it into existing iPhone app. Thank goodness for branches in Git.